# Covid vaccine second dose side effects and immunity

Tags: immune-system, side-effects, vaccine, covid

Does experiencing side effects such as fever/headache/muscle ache after the second dose of vaccine mean that immune system is weak and catching covid would have been more dangerous in comparison to those who didn't experience any side effects?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Seems to be the same Q as https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/28872/does-severity-of-covid-vaccine-side-effects-correlate-with-or-suggest-anything-a  And I personally don't see how it's answerable but with speculation...

Comment: @Fizz That question is now closed. (You know you have enough rep to cast close votes, right? Please do so!)